# Want to make a magento site, product's weight oriented

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-options, payment-methods, partial-payments

I want to start a magento site with the following constraints

1. Product should be listed according to weight instead of price
2. The customer is allowed to add any number of product in his cart and total weight shows up at checkout time
3. The customer can place the final order with COD option after paying some minimum amount online calculated dynamically based upon the total weight of items in the cart.

P.S. I am a good programmer and knows basics of Javascript and PHP but I am new to magento.
For this site I will be using a paid template purchased from ThemeForest